# How to use CONCAT and NOT LIKE in an SQL Update in PHP request

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, android-studio

Hi i am creating an android app which i am currently at a halt because my sql skills are not up to scratch. I am using json.response to run the following php.

**Situation:** I am checking the table column (users_watched) to see if the user_id exists inside it based on title_text, since its a number i am using ,1,(example) commas around the number so it doesn't get confused with something like 101, and returns that value. If the user_id is not in the row, then add it to the end of the string.

**Text Data:** user_id = '10,' - watched_title = 'video_title' - temp_user_id = ',10,'

```
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$watched_title = $_POST["watched_title"];
$temp_user_id = $_POST["temp_user_id"];
$like_input = "'%".$temp_user_id."%'";  

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE videos SET users_watched = CONCAT(users_watched, '?') WHERE users_watched NOT LIKE ? AND title_text = ?");    
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $user_id, $like_input, $watched_title);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```

**Result:** It is not adding the value to the end of the appropriate string.

**Expected Output** Add user_id = 10, to the end of the string based on videos_watched

Comment: Can you please provide one data sample and expected output as well.

Comment: I'm confused. Why (or how) are you using php in android studio? :|

Comment: @Suraz i have updated with test data and expected output, the idea is, i am creating a list of videos, then i am adding the user id to the list so i can see if they have watched it, i then split by a comma.

Comment: @Leo [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M) If you see that link its a tutorial for how to use php with android studio. Quick answer: You add your php file to online db, then you reference the url in yours java code, that is how you run it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php

    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
    $watched_title = $_POST["watched_title"];
    $temp_user_id = $_POST["temp_user_id"];
    $like_input = "%".$temp_user_id."%";  

try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname','$username', '$pass');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE videos SET users_watched = CONCAT(users_watched, :userid) WHERE users_watched NOT LIKE :like_input AND title_text = :watched_title");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':like_input', $like_input);
    $stmt->bindParam(':watched_title', $watched_title);
    $stmt->execute();   

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Oh i see, so thats another way to write the php document, and it helps with debugging, awesome thanks man :D